# Linux 101 - How to loop thru all directories?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm new to linux and working with git. I have a directory (code) with a dozen sub directories (git repositories).

I want two commands I can run to

- Get the current status of all repositories.
- git pull new changes for all repositories.

I know this is probably very simple for someone who knows what they are doing, I just can't get the right loop executing (I am looping all files, not directories).

Thanks! Kyle

Answer (score 5):

Try the [`find`(1)](http://linuxmanpages.com/man1/find.1.php) command. You can tell it to search only for directories (`-type d`) and to search only a specified depth from your working directory (`-maxdepth x`). Further you can tell find to execute a command on every match instead of just printing its name (`-exec`).

For example, to run `git status` on all directories in your current working directory, do

```
find -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec git status {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [mr](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/mr/) utility.  It's designed expressly for this purpose.